# Producing permutations of a set of integers in C++. Getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, recursion, stl, set

I was trying to solve a problem which involved producing all the permutations of a set of numbers. The idea seemed simple enough (code below), but I keep getting segmentation faults. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
void permute(set<int>& s, vector<int>& v) {
    if(s.empty()) {
        // read the permutation in v.
        return;
    }
    set<int>::iterator i;
    for(i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++) {
        int x = *i;
        s.erase(i);
        v.push_back(x);
        permute(s, v);
        v.pop_back();
        s.insert(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: erasing and inserting is messing your iterators, you can't just ignore that. Check their return values and update `i` accordingly

Comment: Augh, are you aware, that `std::set` is sorted container and as such, no matter in what order you insert elements, they will end up in sorted (ascending) order?

Comment: Also, as already noted you are doing bad things to iterators with the recursion, as they become invalid during the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

To produce all permutations in C++ use `std::next_permutation`. The problem here is that you cannot permutate the set, because the ordering is **preset** by the key comparator operator (in your case the less than operator). What you can do is store your values in a non associative container and then have a go.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void permut(std::set<int> const &inp, std::vector<int> &all_permutations)
{
    vector<int> tmp(inp.size());
    copy(inp.begin(), inp.end(), tmp.begin());

    vector<int> all_permutations;
    do 
    {
        copy(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), back_inserter(all_permutations));
    } while (std::next_permutation(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The `permute()` function calls itself recursively while iterating over the mutable containers and making changes.  This violates iterator validity promises.

You might try something based on std::next_permutation()

Answer (score -2):

I have not gone into the precise behaviour you can expect from a set, but it seems pretty clear that the things you are doing inside the for loop are enough to make the iterator invalid. I would suggest redesigning things so that you have two sets, and work through one (which starts off full) while generating the permutation in the other (which starts off empty).

Comment: Sorry, but suggesting using sorted container to store a permutation doesn't seem like a good answer.

Comment: You are of course correct! I had failed to think the implications of a set through.